# Issue augmenting the react types in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm trying to add the new hooks to react in typescript (last I checked, they weren't available on DefinitelyTyped), but it's not working.

I've made a file `types/react.d.ts` that looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';

declare module 'react' {
  function useState<T>(
    initialState: T | (() => T),
  ): [T, (newState: T | ((oldState: T) => T)) => void];
}
```

but when I try to use it, it's not working.

[image]

Comment: It works for me.  Make sure you don't have `files`/`include`/`exclude` settings in `tsconfig.json` that are preventing `types/react.d.ts` from being loaded.  If you publish a repository that reproduces the problem, I'll look at it.

Comment: Works for me too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the issue was related to `tsconfig.json` configuration, as suggested by Matt McCutchen.

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to the Flow types for React Hooks here - https://github.com/facebook/flow/pull/7149/

They should be pretty similar to TypeScript.

In Flow, it looks like:

```
declare type BasicStateAction<S> = (S => S) | S;
declare type Dispatch<A> = A => void;

declare export function useState<S>(
  initialState: (() => S) | S,
): [S, Dispatch<BasicStateAction<S>>];
```

Comment: The types were not the problem. Augmenting another module was.